# Half of shape transparent

Tags: error

[image]For some reason half of the shape is all blurry. Its only like this on the viewport shading tab and is normal on all the other ones. It also does not appear to be a lighting issue (Apologies if this is a dumb question. I'm new at this)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: what do you mean by blurry? do you mean transparent? could you please highlight the problem?